# ReadFile() returns false with GetLastError returning ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER

Tags: readfile, usb-drive

I'm trying to access an external USB 3.0 drive using ReadFile() but it keeps returning false on ReadFile and GetLastError() returns ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER. The following is my code excerpt:

```
#define RPD_SECTOR_SIZE 512
HANDLE hDevice = 0;
char driveName[256];
BYTE *pData;
DWORD len;
bool rv;
int errCode;
sprintf(driveName, "\\\\.\\PhysicalDrive1");
hDevice = CreateFile (driveName,
                      GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
                      FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
                      NULL,
                      OPEN_EXISTING,
                      FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING,
                      NULL);
pData = (BYTE *)VirtualAlloc(NULL, RPD_SECTOR_SIZE, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);
if (pData == NULL) {
  return RPD_MEMORY_ALLOCATION_ERROR;
}
rv = ReadFile(hDevice, pData, RPD_SECTOR_SIZE, &len, NULL);
if (!rv) {
  errCode = GetLastError();
}
```

The funny thing is that the code works perfectly for another USB 2.0 drive. Is there anything I should be doing differently to access USB 3.0 drives?

Does anyone know what's the invalid parameter?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out my RPD_SECTOR_SIZE was set to 512 bytes, and that worked with my other drives, but not with the USB 3.0 ones, which apparently has 4KB sector sizes.